# Split Gridview values into other column having same header, if row count value exceeds some limit?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am getting data from SQL DB and displaying those data in Gridview in asp webpage, now I want to spilt those data into other columns based on row values.
For Ex: I have two columns like Employee Id, Employee Name if row values exceeds 100, I want to display remaining data into other columns with same header.
Here, same header means data is coming from same table, I have requirement like I want to display to other column if row value exceeds 100 count.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another Grid view next to the existing one, which will contain the same columns... plus It's not clear what you mean by 'row values' I based my answer on Row Count exceeds 100.

Comment: I added a extra info, plz check and help me

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a way to span between 2 columns, it requires lot of work:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/87004d70-482a-4b86-ba18-371670254b6a/how-to-merge-headers-in-a-datagridview

Concerning the split of the values to 2 columns, following an idea (it will not work in case the second column is >100, it requires some adjustements)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int limitRows = 100;
            var col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            var col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            gridProduct.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gridProduct.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            gridProduct.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;

            gridProduct.Columns.Add(col1);
            gridProduct.Columns.Add(col2);
            gridProduct.Columns.Add(col3);

            var colIndex = 0;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                if (i == limitRows)
                {
                    colIndex = 1;
                    rowIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (i > limitRows)
                    rowIndex++;
                else
                    rowIndex = gridProduct.Rows.Add();

                gridProduct.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value = string.Format("Val for row {0}", i);
                gridProduct.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value = string.Format("Another val for row {0}", i);
            }
        }
```